# Table Head Spacing

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
.content{
  width: 1133px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e2e7ee;
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

th{
  width: 61px;
  height: 12px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: #516173;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

th:first-child{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabulka">
            <table class="content">
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Com ID</th>
                    <th>Leg ID</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</section>
```

Hello,

I´m making a table where I need to adjust spacing because of a ui design. But I run into a problem. It just spreads evenly. I tried using `:first-child` but the rest still won't move acording to the design. So if there is somebody who know how to help me, please do.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width` settings on the cells, for example using `:nth-child` selectors, Those can be in percentage values, according to the approximate width relations between the columns that you want.

(And in case you don't want the table to spread across the whole page, just apply a `width` setting to the `table` tag)

Answer (score 0):

Use `th:first-child` and `th:not(:first-child)` selector and give `width: X%`.

```css
.content{
  width: 1133px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e2e7ee;
  background-color: #f1f4f8;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

th{
  width: 61px;
  height: 12px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
  color: #516173;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

th{
    text-align: left;
}

tr.info>th:first-child {
  width: 30%;
}

tr.info>th:not(:first-child) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<section class="tabulka">
            <table class="content">
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Com ID</th>
                    <th>Leg ID</th>
                    <th>Size</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>

                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
</section>
```